# The meaning of the /sys/class/net/<interface>/type value

Tags: linux

For each network interface linux contains a directory in /sys/class/net
There is a file with name "type".
Its value is:
1 - for wlan0/eth0.
772 - for lo.
512 - for rmnet0/rmnet1/...

So what is the meaning of these values? Where can I find any descriptions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This header will show you the way to the world of work with interfaces:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h#L30

There are many, but the most common:

```
#define ARPHRD_ETHER    1       /* Ethernet 10Mbps      */
#define ARPHRD_LOOPBACK 772     /* Loopback device      */
```